# View with alignParentBottom attribute covering Edittext when keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `Fragment` with nested `fragments`, using a `Viewpager`. When the keyboard opens, the `RelativeLayout` covers the `EditText`

[image: relative layout with <code>viewpagerindicator</code> covering the <code>EditText</code>]

Is there any way to open the keyboard without the `RelativeLayout` go up?

Parent `Fragment` layout:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/vp_service_creation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rr_semi_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-180dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/half_circle_green"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <dk.ostebaronen.droid.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
           android:id="@+id/pi_circles"
           android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="90dp"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your EditText placed inside viewpager?

Comment: yes, in a viewpager

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different approach for your case.

Option 1:

You can try `adjustNothing`, but the keyboard will potentially cover your EditText.

```xml
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

You can refer to the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility)

Option 2:

If you want to keep `adjustPan` for auto push the view up when the EditText is covered by the keyboard, I suggest you add a listener to detect the keyboard visibility. When the keyboard is visible, hide `rr_semi_circle` layout. When user finish input text and keyboard is hidden, show the `rr_semi_circle` layout again.

Answer (score 0):

Add ScrollView at the following sample like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/vp_service_creation"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rr_semi_circle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-180dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/half_circle_green"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <dk.ostebaronen.droid.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
       android:id="@+id/pi_circles"
       android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="90dp"
    />
   </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your androidManifest.xml, this will not make the UX to resize the components inside but pan itself and give you the same output you desire.